# Create a point on a line after a specific distance from startpoint

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to create a point on a line after 10 meters from the beginning of the line. In postgis it is possible to create a point on a certain fraction of total length of linestring (st_line_interpolate_point), but in this case I can't specify the distance of the point.

I don't know if it possible to do something like that, because line could be shorter than the distance that i set to place the point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where the new point should be placed when the reference line is shorter than 10 m? Would it be simply on the overshoot of line between start point and end point? When the line is longer that 10 m would you be happy with st_line_interpolate point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend here is **ST_LineInterpolatePoint**. Look here for more information: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html.

You have to compute the right fraction to get your 10 metres. So this is done with this little calculcation:

```
10 metres = ST_Length(the_line) * fraction 
fraction = 10 metres / ST_Length(the_line)
```

So the result is (like the other posts described):

```
ST_LineInterpolatePoint(the_geom, 10 / ST_Length(the_line))
```

Watch out the coordinate system you use so the 10 is 10 metres indeed.

Answer (score 1):

ST_LineInterpolatePoint(the_line, 10/ST_Length(the_line))

Answer (score 1):

You can use st_project function. A sample is as follows. To find a point at a distance of 100 meters between points '77.0541494 28.5091006' and '77.054473971709 28.5095594' from the first point.

```
select st_astext(st_project('POINT(77.0541494 28.5091006)'::geography, 100, st_azimuth(st_geomfromtext('POINT(77.0541494 28.5091006)'), st_geomfromtext('POINT(77.054473971709 28.5095594)'))));
```

OUTPUT: **POINT(77.0547393477234 28.5098372103161)**

For reference:

1. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html
2. http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Azimuth.html